# Шаблон "числоХчисло" в MSSQL

Tags: sql, sql-server, маска

Имеется текст, например, 'название товара 10x54'
Необходимо написать такое регулярное выражение, что бы извлечь подстроку 10x54, при этом числа могут могут быть в диапазоне от 1 до 1000.

`select PATINDEX('%[1-9]x[1-9]%','название товара 10x54')` таким образом я получаю индекс где начинается шаблон числоXчисло

`select SUBSTRING('название товара 10x54',PATINDEX('%[0-9]x[0-9]%','название товара 10x54'),3)` таким образом я вывожу полученный результат

Comment: TSQL не поддерживает регулярные выражения.

Comment: А что я тогда написала выше?

Comment: Фигню. *`select PATINDEX('%[1-9]x[1-9]%','название товара 10x54')` таким образом я получаю индекс где начинается шаблон числоXчисло* - а то, что возвращается ноль, не смутило? Сервер так вот и ищет то, что меж знаков процента - литерально. https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2017&fiddle=dd0c2b40ee2ad6280e104e09706aa5a0

Comment: "Wildcard pattern" != "regex pattern".

Comment: select PATINDEX('%[0-9]x[1-9]%','название товара 10x54')   если написать так, то вернёт 18

Comment: у вас там произвольные совсем варианты есть, а-ля `1x999` или `756x1`, то есть длина не симметрична?

Comment: да, варианты произвольные могут быть